# SonarQube/IntelliJ - How to Hide Warnings?

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarqube

I've install the SonarQube plugin in IntelliJ and it's working great - it's a huge help. But how do I turn the warnings off? Since my team just started using SonarQube, we have thousands of issues and every single one is showing up in my IDE and it's getting *very* distracting :'(

I don't want to uninstall the plugin and reinstall every time I want to run an analysis - but I do want the warnings to go away on-demand so I can concentrate on getting some work done. I don't have time to just fix Sonar issues all day.

Thanks

Comment: It depends on plugin you use - I've struggled with same problem with "community edition", but didn't get to anything. Which is a shame, since Eclipse plugins not only enabled such actions as hiding, but also updating status of issues, assigning etc...

Answer (score 1):

This is not a perfect solution but you can try to disassociate the project (in the same UI used to update project association, there is a button to remove association).